# Makefile doesn't find shell command

Tags: linux, makefile

In my Makefile im trying to get the absolute path to a directory with the find command. Here is a snippet of the Makefile

```
PATH := $(shell find /home/ -type d -path "*/name" -print -quit)
all: create

create:
       mkdir -p otherPathName
```

The Makefile works fine when I delete the PATH := $(shell .... ) line, but when it is included I get this error

```
make: mkdir: Command not found
Makefile:22: recipe for target 'create' failed
make: *** [create] Error 127
```

For further actions in the Makefile the absolute path received from 'find' is necessary, but I don't know how to fix this error.

Comment: make invokes a shell which will call `mkdir`. THat shell is going to search through its `PATH` to find `mkdir`.  You have modified PATH. Use a different name.

Comment: Try concatenating to `path` instead of replacing it.

Comment: Oh wow... what a silly mistake :D Changed the name worked, thanks :)